# iOS app review - unsure whether I choose 'wait to release' or 'release immediately'

Tags: iphone, xcode

**Update:  The app is already configured in iTunes connect I *can't remember* which option I choose.**

I have an app sitting in iTunes Connect waiting for upload but I am unsure whether I choose 'wait to release' or 'release immediately'.

How do I ensure it is set to 'wait to release' before uploading my binary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select wait for release option, in app summary page, new version will be listed as
**"Release Control: Hold for Developer Release"**.

Comment: I do not remember which option I choose so I want to go back and see or change it

Comment: As I said in above, you can see the option in the app summary page. (iTunes Connect->Manage Your Applications->YOUR APP->[listed under new version]). If you could not see "Release Control: Hold for Developer Release", then it means you have choose the release immediately option.

Comment: I do not see that I just see waiting for review.  I have set the release date to be in the future but ideally I would just like it to wait until I am ready

Comment: My app is waiting for review however I don't know whether I set it to release immediately or wait to release.  I want to know and if possible change it to wait to release

Comment: If you could not see "Release Control: Hold for Developer Release", then it means you have choose the release immediately option. And you cannot change it in this step. You have to developer-reject your binary and upload it again.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose wait to release,You have to release your app after apple accepting your app.If you choose 'release immediately',It will be automatically released after apple accepts your app.

Answer (score 0):

I always prefer the "wait to release" option.

This gives you the possibility to *not* release an update if you notice a bug in the last minute. Also you can sync your release with other time dependent actions like:

- marketing campaigns
- backend changes
- ...

Answer (score 0):

I believe you confirm that option after you upload the binary as part of the submission process.